# Can I set a random state for the Complement Naive Bayes?

Tags: scikit-learn, naivebayes

I note I can set the random state in random forest classifier, but not in Complement Naive Bayes. I get error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

I assume this is because naive_bayes is computing the probability of each class?

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ComplementNB
model= ComplementNB(random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the model doesn't do anything needed to be randomly initialized or generated. see the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L995-L1028) for more details.

Be in case you want to reset the random seed in that line from your own side, you can do something like this.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

def set_random_seed(seed=0):
  np.random.seed(seed)
  random.seed(seed)
```

Then you can reset the random seed right before calling your model

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ComplementNB

set_random_seed(0)
model= ComplementNB()
```

Read more about the [mechanism of Complement Naive Bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#complement-naive-bayes).